# Eclipse 4 rcp load layout not works with binding context

Tags: eclipse, layout, eclipse-rcp, key-bindings

I have an application, in which I can save the load perspective layout.
Everything works until I add `Binding Context` to any `Part`. If I set `Binding Context` to part, then save layout, then close application and try to load layout in opened application again I get exception:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 2 2016-10-16 20:54:37.922
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A handle object may not have a null identifier
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activate(EclipseContext.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activateBranch(EclipseContext.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener$1.run(ShellActivationListener.java:95)
```

here is my steps:

test handler class:

```
public class Test {
    
    @Execute
    public void execute(EPartService partService) {
        System.out.println("Test handler");
    }

}
```

Create handler:
[image: Handler config]

Then create `Binding Contect`, `Binding table` with `KeyBinding` [image]

finally add `BindingContext` to part:
[image]

Loading and saving layout code is same as in this tutorial [Model persistence article 3](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ModelPersistence/article.html)

Maybe someone knows what problem can be and is there are any solution?

Comment: I would try reporting this on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org) as I doubt anyone else is likely to be able to help.

Comment: I have no account there... Still expecting maybe someone had similar problem.